# AWS CloudWatch Error "There was an error while trying to get graph data."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Facing below error in AWS CloudWatch widgets, the strange part is it worked with the same code earlier and now it throwing this error for few widgets. Any hints or ideas on how to debug this error?

```
"There was an error while trying to get graph data."
```